# playframework obtaining the URL + queryString of a play.api.libs.ws.WS.WSRequest

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have this request :

```
  WS.url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")
    .withQueryString(
    "origin" -> Seq(oLa, oLn).mkString(","),
    "destination" -> Seq(dLa.toString, dLn.toString).mkString(","),
    "sensor" -> "false",
    "key" -> "IzaSyBAFWRgLWNKIEB2xCdm11ilCfzyVxJ2dasNw"
  ).get
```

I'd like to see the "raw" URL + queryString,

This post suggests using wireshark :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/bm_pf3uhcbY/XTzP0d36gKgJ

It happens I'm under SSL...

Answer (score 3):

This is the way:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest

val ahcRequest = req.asInstanceOf[AhcWSRequest].buildRequest()
Logger.debug("Uri: " + ahcRequest.getUri)
```

**UPDATE for play 2.6:**

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSRequest

val ahcRequest = req.asInstanceOf[AhcWSRequest]
Logger.debug("Uri: " + ahcRequest.uri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by "raw URL".  Do you mean this:

```
val u = WS.url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")
    .withQueryString(
    "origin" -> Seq(oLa, oLn).mkString(","),
    "destination" -> Seq(dLa.toString, dLn.toString).mkString(","),
    "sensor" -> "false",
    "key" -> "IzaSyBAFWRgLWNKIEB2xCdm11ilCfzyVxJ2dasNw"
  )
println(u.toString)
u.get
```